# Should the Swift programming language be explicitly added to the description of the [init] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Right now, the [init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/init) tag's description reads, "May refer to Linux init, an abbreviation of initialization - giving variables a "starting" value, or Python's __init__ class initiation method."  However, Swift also has an `init` method for both classes and structs, and multiple questions on the front page (4 out of the first 15 when I last viewed the most recent questions tagged with [init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/init)) are about (and also tagged with) Swift.

Should the tag description be edited to read, "May refer to Linux init, an abbreviation of initialization - giving variables a "starting" value, or Python's __init__ class initiation method, or Swift's class/struct initialization method."?

Also, I'm not 100% sure of this, but shouldn't "initiation" in the existing description actually be "initi**aliz**ation"?

Comment: This should be a disambiguation request. If tag description starts with "May refer to", it is a telltale sign the tag is as useful as a fifth wheel in a car.

Comment: On an off-note, folks, *please* use [proper tag formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags) in posts related to tags!

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: No worries, regarding tag formatting - it is a general plea to others from me (so tired of fixing those). The guidance on it is not easily found, unfortunately, being tucked away in the "more" section.

Comment: Perhaps change the tag to refer to the initialization of an object, structure, blob of data, or any entity which contains state that must be prepared prior to usage of the entity?

Answer (score 8):

This tag should simply be made a synonym of [initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialization). It’s a shorthand for said word, and the usages referred to in the current tag wiki, are `__init__` in Python, and with your new suggestion, `init` in Swift. These are constructors, or initializers, for objects. This makes it quite clear the only reasonable course of action is to make it a synonym.

Comment: Well, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76145315/7395227)'s an example of [tag:init] being used on a question not about initializing an object, so I guess that speaks against my "only reasonable course of action". Well, I'd rather prefer removing the tag from this question, though, as it's not really useful there.

Comment: On a side note I also found [construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/construction) which may be a possible synonym target, as well as [creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/creation), though the later states "Do not use" in the tag wiki, which is again a great description for a tag..